# How do I get my links to glow on :hover with CSS3?

Tags: html, css, glow

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Glowing Text (HTML CSS)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5201949/glowing-text-html-css)

So I'm looking for a 100% css solution for a text glow effect. **I tried text-shadow** but I couldn't get it looking how I wanted. I was able to achieve the effect with box-shadow. However, that only glows around the outside of the elements edges, and leaves the inside blank. Here is a picture:

[image]

How do I get a nice looking outer glow like above, without the blank inside?

my code is just a simple `<li><a></a></li>` , with hover css on both the li, and a tags.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: http://nicolasgallagher.com/css-drop-shadows-without-images/demo/

Answer (score 16, accepted):

```
a:hover { text-shadow: 0 0 5px #ff0000; }
```

Comment: If you read above, I state that text-shadow is not the effect i'm looking for. Unless it is able to be as large as what my picture shows..

Comment: Well, your image wasn't there when I posted this answer, but if you research text-shadow you will quickly learn that you can play with the size, blur and color to achieve the effect you are looking for.

Comment: Thanks, honestly that wasn't working too well before. I finally figured it out though. I just applied the shadow 3 times at 15px; Thanks again.

Answer (score 2):

what about a text-shadow on hover

like this

```
<li>
  <a></a>
</li>
```

css

```
li a:hover {
  text-shadow: 2px 2px 10px #000000;

  filter: dropshadow(color=#000000, offx=2, offy=2);
}
```

**[FIDDLE HERE](http://jsfiddle.net/wRhUa/2/)**

Generate your css 3 properties **[HERE](http://css3generator.com/)**

Comment: The community dont just give you have to work some self what about going to the generator i made and make your glow like you want it and then add it with in the css i posted

Answer (score 0):

You can do this with an extra element

[jsfiddle example](http://jsfiddle.net/Pj94p/) (or [fullscreen](http://jsfiddle.net/Pj94p/show))

HTML

```
<ul id="nav">
    <li><span></span><a href="#">Home</a></li>
    <li><span></span><a href="#">Products</a></li>
    <li><span></span><a href="#">Really Long Nav Item</a></li>
</ul>
```

CSS

```
#nav {background-color:#000;overflow:hidden;}
#nav li {float:left;position:relative;}
#nav a {display:block;background:transparent;color:#fff;font-weight:bold;text-decoration:none;padding:20px;position:relative;}

#nav li:hover span {
    position:absolute;
    left:50%;top:50%;
    margin-left:-35%;
    width:70%;height:0px;
    box-shadow:0 0 20px 12px rgba(150, 180, 200, .6);
    border-radius:10px 6px;
}
```

Potentially you could skip the extra `<span>` element and do this with the `:before` pseudo-element on the anchor or list item
    ​